# WIX Installer - Upgrading application does not always remove prior installed application

Tags: wix

First of all, I've tried to find explanations on several forums but I didn't
found a topic that might explain the behavior observed.
In advance, I apologize if I missed one.

---

#### The observed behavior:

When upgrading product with a new installer, prior installation is not always removed correctly.

---

#### What changed between previous and current installer wix setup project:

- The previous product installer was installing under Directory `<DirectoryId="ProgramFiles64Folder">`
- The new installer has been updated is installing under `<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">`
- Checking for .Net framework 4.5 or newer installed
- Use `<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />`

---

#### When I upgrade product on my computer (Windows 10 - 64 bits OS) everything works fine:

1. Previous product installed under "C:\Program Files\" is uninstalled correctly - See logs extract:

> RemoveExistingProducts: Application:{F6E83B3C-CA4D-4FE2-BB54-4D5156D9EB98}, Command line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={DB2D1294-EA5F-4BEF-BFBC-A236E0DCDEB3} CLIENTPROCESSID=21584 CLIENTUILEVEL=0 REMOVE=ALL

2. New product is correctly installed under "C:\Program Files (x86)\"

---

#### But on other hand, a user has encountered a problem: previous product is not uninstalled (Windows 7 - 64 bits OS)

1. What I can see when upgrading with verbose logs is that previous version is
   found:

> RemoveExistingProducts: Application: {F6E83B3C-CA4D-4FE2-BB54-4D5156D9EB98}, Command line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={E71A5696-B038-4EEE-9B4A-DE0A3D84045E}  CLIENTUILEVEL=0 REMOVE=ALL

2. When CostFinalize sequence is started to remove existing product,
   directory structure location is changed to "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\" **where product is not yet installed**:

> MSI (s) (6C:60) [12:17:56:505]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ProgramFiles64Folder property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\'.
>
> MSI (s) (6C:60) [12:17:56:505]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CompanyDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\'.
>
> MSI (s) (6C:60) [12:17:56:505]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\' will substitute 17 characters in 'C:\Program Files\Company\Company Product\' folder path. (mask argument = 0, the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
>
> MSI (s) (6C:60) [12:17:56:505]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLFOLDER property. Its current value is 'C:\Program Files\Company\Company Product'. Its new value: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Company Product\'.

- I have the complete upgrade log files (the one working and the other failing)
- I can give you more details if needed on the wix file.wxs used to generate
  msi

---

#### Questions:

1. Has anyone faced a such behavior ?
2. Is the only solution to uninstall prior version and install the new
   one ?

In advance, thanks to all !

Answer (score 0):

Did you followed the component guid change guidelines?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367849(v=vs.85).aspx

When you change the folder/name you had to change the guid's.

Comment: Hi Bernd, Thanks so much for your advise. In fact, I didn't follow this guideline because it seems (for me) that only changing INSTALLFOLDER (component installed are the same as before technically) didn't meen to change component GUIDs 
I'm gonna try it and give a feedback soon !
Thanks !

Comment: First point is validated: On my computer, no regression observed:
Prior version is still uninstalled correctly and new one is installed correctly too.
Next step: validate the fix with my user. 
It may takes more time to be validated (1 or 2 weeks) but be sure I will let you know how it works !